# how to reduce a fraction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

I solved expression and saw this solving, but I didn't see the way to reduce one.
$$\begin{align}\frac{a+2\sqrt{ab}-3b}{ab(a - \sqrt{ab} - 3\sqrt{ab -3b})}=\frac{1}{ab}\end{align}$$
Can you show me the way to reduce one?

Comment: There are conditions missing on $a$ and $b$. Try your equality with $a=b=1$...

Comment: no. In book the expression don't have any conditions. $\frac{1}{ab}$ is the answer

Comment: Well then take the example $a=b=1$ and observe that equality is wrong...

Comment: @Surb, I understood. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality you wrote is obviously false, or at the very best, is not true for all values of $a,b$. For example, taking $a=b=1$ results in $0$ on the left hand side and $1$ on the right.